# Strategy to sell after X amount of bars

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to add to a strategy, something very simple - to sell after X amount of bars when the trigger has been reached. I tried this code recommended online, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
if sellFb == true and buyFb == false
    strategy.entry("BreakDown", strategy.short, comment="Short")  

if buyFb == true and sellFb == false
    strategy.entry("BreakUp", strategy.long, comment="Buy")



if sellFb or buyFb
    alert(txt, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    n = 4
    open_idx = strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades-1)
    diff_idx = bar_index - open_idx

    if (diff_idx >= n)
        strategy.close("BreakUp")
        strategy.close("BreakDown")
```

It doesn't close the strategy after the bars, only closes it when the next opposite direction trade comes (short/buy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you only execute that piece of code if `sellFb` or `buyFb` is `true`.

Instead, you should be checking for that in the global scope.

```
if sellFb == true and buyFb == false
    strategy.entry("BreakDown", strategy.short, comment="Short")  

if buyFb == true and sellFb == false
    strategy.entry("BreakUp", strategy.long, comment="Buy")  

if sellFb or buyFb
    alert(txt, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

n = 4
open_idx = strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.opentrades-1)
diff_idx = bar_index - open_idx

if (diff_idx >= n)
    strategy.close("BreakUp")
    strategy.close("BreakDown")
```